# How can i print a sheet by using php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this my jquery code

```
function print_transaction(cid){
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>Transaction/print',
    data:{'cid':cid},
    success: function(done){
      print(done);

    }
});}
```

My php code:

```
echo"hello world";
```

And this the HTML code

```
 <a href='#' onclick=\"print_transaction('43643643643')\" > print</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code simply prints what it receives from the server. so to print a sheet, simply print some sheet from your php code and it will be usable on your html. for example:
PHP:

```
echo "<table><td>Transaction id</td><td>".$_POST['cid']."</td></table>";
```

HTML:

```
 <a href='#' onclick=\"print_transaction('43643643643')\" > print</a>
<div id="response"></div>
```

JS:

```
function print_transaction(cid){
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>Transaction/print',
    data:{'cid':cid},
    success: function(done){
      document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=done;

    }
});}
```

Comment: OP means, print as in print, not place onto dom

Comment: then the question is not clear, what to you want to achieve with this code?? Do you want to save data and print response?? or maybe manipulate the data and print a document to a pdf or maybe print to a printer?? explain yourself well